# Source Terraform Module From Sub-Directories In a BitBucket Repository With A different branch

Tags: terraform, bitbucket, terraform-provider-aws

I have a terraform modules repository with different set of modules with below structure

```
BitBucket Repository(URL: git@bitbucket.org:/{repoName}.git?ref=develop
└── modules
    ├── s3
    │   ├── locals.tf
    │   ├── main.tf
    │   ├── output.tf
    │   └── variables.tf
    └── tfstate
        └── main.tf
```

develop is the branch that I want to use which I have given in the source URL. I am calling the module repository as given below:

```
├── examples
│   ├── gce-nextgen-dev.tfvars
│   └── main.tf
```

main.tf

```
module "name" {
  source = "git@bitbucket.org:{url}/terraform-modules.git? ref=develop/"
  bucketName = "terraformbucket"
  environment = "dev"
  tags = map("ExtraTag", "ExtraTagValue")
}
```

How can I call the modules from sub-directories which is in a BitBucket repository.
It works if I remove the ref=develop from the URL and just give git@bitbucket.org:{url}/terraform-modules.git//modules//s3
But I don't want to use master but develop branch in this case.

Comment: Is your error because of the whitespace typo before the `ref`?

Comment: No it is not because of that infact I made a mistake while typing it here. Ignore that space for now.The ref that I am giving is "?ref=develop//modules//s3"

Answer (score 0):

I also have a Bitbucket repo that contains multiple modules.

This is how I reference a specific tag, which I assume will be the same for a branch (assuming you are using a public key)

```
module "ecs_cluster" {
  source               = "git@bitbucket.org:[ORG_NAME]/terraform-modules.git/1.0.0//ecs/cluster"
  resource_name_prefix = local.resource_name_prefix
  vpc_id               = module.networking.vpc_id
}
```

If your repository is public, and you want to use `https`, then you can do the following

```
module "ecs_cluster" {
  source               = "git::https://bitbucket.org/[ORG_NAME]/terraform-modules/src/1.0.0//ecs/cluster"
  resource_name_prefix = local.resource_name_prefix
  vpc_id               = module.networking.vpc_id
}
```